# Outlook Ribbon Customization

Tags: visual-c++, outlook, ribbon, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

i have added a tab in outlook ribbon in using vc++ in visual studio.but i need to hide the tab when opening a perticular mail in outlook 2010.
i have attched snapshot for the same 
[image: first]
first image shows : i have added custom tab and it is loading correctly when i open outlook.
[image: second]
now come to requirements ..
second image shows : custom tab i have to hide from there when i am opening a perticular mail in outlook and i have to add the same below More option in outlook

what xml to added or removed to make it work

help needed work in progress.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the tab `getVisible` event in your Ribbon UI.

```xml
<ribbon>
    <tabs>
        <tab id="MyTab" getVisible="MyTab_GetVisible" label="MyTab">
            <group label="MyGroup" id="MyGroup" >
                <button id="MyButton" size="large" label="MyButton" imageMso="HappyFace" onAction="OnMyButtonClick"/>
            </group>
        </tab>
    </tabs>
</ribbon>
```

To toggle the tab visibility, you need to implement `MyTab_GetVisible` depending on your needs. See [SampleAddin on MSDN for reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692172.aspx#OfficeOLExtendingUI_SampleAddin).

```cs
// Only show MyTab when inspector is a read note.
public bool MyTab_GetVisible(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{
    if (control.Context is Outlook.Inspector)
    {
        Outlook.Inspector oInsp = control.Context as Outlook.Inspector;
        if (oInsp.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem oMail = oInsp.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            return oMail.Sent;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply 
but i am not getting where i should implement this MyTab_GetVisible()

i have implemented all my methods in Cconncet.h file .. and i have to implement in visual c++.  Help needed .

Comment: @zytham - this implementation would be placed in whichever class implements `IRibbonExtensibility`