# How to show outlook ribbon only on clicking inbox and sentitems folder?

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook-addin

I am developing an Outlook add-in. I added a ribbon with a few controls like dropdown, check box, etc.

I want to show the ribbon only when the Inbox folder or Sent Items folder is selected. Is there anyway I can hide and show my ribbon?

I tried few approach like by loading the ribbon control as xml file but my ribbon is not even loading if try with ribbon as xml way.

I tried this also.
[Outlook Ribbon Customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10331029/outlook-ribbon-customization)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `getVisible` callback in the Ribbon XML markup to be able to update controls visibility at runtime dynamically.

The Ribbon UI (aka Fluent UI) controls are described in depth in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)

The [FolderSwitch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865625.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the Explorer class is fired when the explorer goes to a new folder, either as a result of user action or through program code. So, you may call the [Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa433552(v=office.12).aspx) or [InvalidateControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa433553(v=office.12).aspx) methods of the IRibbonUI interface which forces the host applications to refresh cached values for the UI controls. See [Overview of the IRibbonUI Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869817.aspx) for more information.

So, when the `FolderSwitch` event is fired for the folder where you need to show your controls you just call the `Invalidate` method and return true in the `getVisible` callback. That's all!

> I tried few approach like by loading the ribbon control as xml file but my ribbon is not even loading if try with ribbon as xml way.

By default, if an VSTO Add-in attempts to manipulate the Microsoft Office user interface (UI) and fails, no error message is displayed. However, you can configure Microsoft Office applications to display messages for errors that relate to the UI. You can use these messages to help determine why a custom Ribbon does not appear, or why a Ribbon appears but no controls appear. Read more about that in the [How to: Show Add-in User Interface Errors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608619.aspx) articles.

Comment: I am using ribbon as visual designer not the xml.
I tried the code in as per this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
ThisAddIn.cs event change method I am able to find get which folder is selected but in CurrentExplorer_Event method I can't get the my ribbon or its controls.
Is there any way I can access the ribbon control in ThisAddIn.cs id so that i can disable the controls?